# Stopping turtles from having negative resources

Tags: netlogo

My model creates a relationship between employees and citizens. Whereby the employees obtain office and then distribute to the employees:

```
globals [

  office-space

]

breed [ offices office ]
breed [ service-desks service-desk ]
breed [ employees employee ]
breed [ citizens citizen ]

offices-own [ money ]
employees-own [ money ]
citizens-own [ money ]

to setup

  clear-all

  create-offices 1 [

    set shape "building institution"
    set size 4
    set color yellow
    set money num-of-money

  ]

  create-employees num-of-employees [

    set shape "person"
    set size 1.5
    set color blue
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor

  ]

  create-citizens num-of-citizens [

    set shape "person"
    set size 1.5
    set color white
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor

  ]

  ;; create 4 service desks

  let service-desk-patches (patch-set patch 0 8 patch 8 0 patch 0 -8 patch -8 0)

  ask service-desk-patches [

    sprout-service-desks 1 [

      set shape "building institution"
      set color pink
      set size 3

    ]

  ]

  ;; create office space

  set office-space patches with [pxcor <= 8 and pxcor >= -8 and pycor <= 8 and pycor >= -8 ]
  ask office-space [set pcolor grey]

  ;; set all employees randomly within the grey box

  place-on-color-employees

  ;; set all citizens randomly outside of the grey box

  place-on-color-citizens

  reset-ticks

end

to place-on-color-employees

  let _patches (patches with [pcolor = grey])

  ask employees [

    move-to one-of (_patches with [not any? turtles-here])

  ]

end

to place-on-color-citizens
  let _patches (patches with [pcolor = black])

  ask citizens [

    move-to one-of (_patches with [not any? turtles-here])

  ]

end

to go

  ask employees [
    
    set label money
    
  ]
  
  ask citizens [ 
    
    set label money
    
  ]
  
  employee-movement-without-money
  employee-take-money
  employee-movement-with-money
  citizens-movement
  citizen-take-money
  
  tick

end

to employee-movement-with-money

  ask employees [

   
    ifelse [ pcolor ] of patch-ahead 1 = black

    [ rt random-float 360 ]
    [ forward 1 ]

    
    let target min-one-of citizens [ distance myself ]

    if money > 0 [

      face target

      fd 1

    ]

  ]

end

to employee-movement-without-money
  
  ask employees [
    
    let target patch  0 0
    
    if ( money = 0 ) or ( money < 0 ) [
      
      face target 
      
      fd 1
      
    ]
    
  ]
    
end


to citizens-movement

  ask citizens [

    ifelse [pcolor] of patch-ahead 1 = grey

    [ rt random-float 360 ]
    [ forward 1 ]

    let target min-one-of service-desks [ distance myself ]

    if money = 0 [

      set heading (towards target )

    ]

  ]

end

to employee-take-money

  ask employees [

    if any? offices-here [

      set money money + 1

      set color green

      ;set label money
    ]

  ]

end



to citizen-take-money

  ask citizens [

    if  any? employees in-radius 0.5 [
      ask employees [
        set money money - 1
          
        ]

      ]
      set money money + 1

      set color orange


    ]

   
end
```

When this model is run, the `employees` collect `money` and go to meet `citizens`, however, in the `citizen-take-money` procedure, I have not found a way to prevent the `citizens` from taking `money` from the `employees` so they don't have negative values. I tried adding the `employee-movement-without-money` to force the `employees` to turn move away from the `citizens`, but they just congregate on `patch 0 0`.

I also tried adjusting the `citizens-take-money` procedures by creating an `if and` arugment:

```
to citizen-take-money

  ask citizens [

    if  (any? employees in-radius 0.5) and (employees money > 0) [
      ask employees [
        set money money - 1

        ]

      ]
      set money money + 1

      set color orange

    ]

end
```

But that didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First piece of advice, build NetLogo models gradually. You need to make sure each piece works before adding the slightly more complicated behaviour. You should never have more than one thing wrong in a NetLogo model at the same time, very hard to debug.

Here, the basic problem appears to be that you are acting on all turtles instead of just the relevant turtle. Here is your supplementary code that tries to introduce a check:

```
to citizen-take-money
  ask citizens [
    if (any? employees in-radius 0.5) and (employees money > 0) [
      ask employees [
        set money money - 1
      ]
  ]
  set money money + 1
  set color orange
]
end
```

First, have a look at your check - conceptually, what are you testing with the second part `employees money > 0`. That doesn't actually look like valid NetLogo code to me, are you trying to ask if there are any employees with with money > 0?

Regardless, let's say it gets past that check, the next line is `ask employees` - at this point you are telling EVERY employee in the model to reduce their money.

What you need to do is just find the right employees and have those ones reduce their money. Something more like:

```
to citizen-take-money
  ask citizens
  [ let nearby employees in-radius 0.5 with [money > 0]
    if any? nearby
    [ ask nearby [ set money money - 1 ]
      set money money + 1
      set color orange
    ]
  ]
end
```

Also, this procedure is asking every citizen to do this and you have named it as if only one citizen is doing it. So think about which way you actually want the process to work.

Finally, what happens if you have several citizens close to several employees. Say 3 citizens reduce their money because they are close to the same employee - at the moment, the employee only increases their money by 1 and the remaining 2 disappears. This is an example of what I mean by build gradually and check it works before adding in the next thing. Perhaps you could have them just change colours if the condition is met before trying to add in the money transfers. That would help you spot that you had lots of people triggered at once.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. They worked for my use case so far. I'm new to Netlogo, so learning a lot. You resolved my issue, but I still am not sure how to prevent a turtle attribute, in this case `money`, from going into negatives, is there a way to make attributes an absolute value?